# Why php fails to report syntax error and Apache crashes with segmentation fault?

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault

I have a class file which has some buggy code e.g

```
  else{
            $stp->Object($a);               
            $abbr = $a->abbr;
        }
        asdf
    }
```

My understanding is that php  should properly display an error message e.g saying sth that  "asdf" is not a class or constant etc . But as I see this peice of code crashes the server with segmentation fault , as my error log file says:

```
[Fri Mar 08 17:21:37 2013] [notice] child pid 8615 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Is it possible to configure php/apache to properly handle these errors ?
Why php is failing to report the error some understandable way . I only see "The connection was reset" 
message in browser.

Specification:
 XAMPP (php 5.3.1)
 MAC OS 10.6
 Xdebuger installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently something is going wrong into Apache, so it can't be properly displayed because the Apache child exit.

I had some similar error once because the PHP error made a redirection to a PHP error file (ex: ErrorDocument 500), which contained the same error, so it redirect to the PHP error page and so on... making a redirection loop.

Apache kill itself to avoid the machine to go down.

---

You have to diagnose what is making Apache die.

To do this, install "strace", eg. on debian :

```
apt-get install strace
```

Then stop your Apache, and start it through strace :

```
strace -f /usr/sbin/apache2ctl
```

Reproduce your problem until your Apache child crash, and try to look into the strace log to find out what happened.

Hope this helped.

Comment: This seems to be issue when using php auto_loader stuff